# Blocking automatic file download to a C Drive folder

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive-cache

I have a low capacity hard drive and purchased a cloud drive to reduce the burden on local drive. The cloud drive creates a cache folder in the AppData (C-drive) which takes a lot of space. I can delete the cache manually but it happens too often. Is there any way to block the sub-folder for the cloud program from AppData folder to prevent it from creating cache again.

Comment: Use a symbolic link to redirect the space to another drive

Comment: Why have you not mentioned which “cloud drive.” It certainly stands to reason someone may be able to offer specific advice to your issue.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm using Pcloud drive.

Comment: @DavidPostill Could you please give some details about the symbolic link procedure.

Comment: @GhoseBishwajit [How to create a Symbolic Link on Windows 10?](//superuser.com/a/1020825)